# Spring WebFlux Route always returns 404

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mockito, spring-webflux

I am working on a simple project which uses Spring Boot 2 with Spring WebFlux using Kotlin.
I wrote test for my handler function (in which I mock the dependencies using Mockito).

However, it seems like my route function does not trigger the handler, as all of my requests return `HTTP 404 NOT FOUND` (even though the route is correct).

I have looked at various other projects to find out what how these tests are supposed to be written ([here](https://github.com/sdeleuze/webflux-kotlin-web-tests), [here](https://blog.knoldus.com/spring-webflux-testing-your-router-functions-with-webtestclient/)), but the problem persists.

The code is as follows (and can also be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/tomirio619/spring-webflux-kotlin-demo)):

**UserRouterTest**

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class, MockitoExtension::class)
@Import(UserHandler::class)
@WebFluxTest
class UserRouterTest {

    @MockBean
    private lateinit var userService: UserService

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userHandler: UserHandler

    @Test
    fun givenExistingCustomer_whenGetCustomerByID_thenCustomerFound() {
        val expectedCustomer = User("test", "test")
        val id = expectedCustomer.userID

        `when`(userService.getUserByID(id)).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(expectedCustomer))

        val router = UserRouter().userRoutes(userHandler)
        val client = WebTestClient.bindToRouterFunction(router).build()

        client.get()
                .uri("/users/$id")
                .accept(MediaType.ALL)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk
                .expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .expectBody(User::class.java)
    }
}
```

**User**

```
@Entity
class User(var username : String, var password: String) {

    @Id
    val userID = UUID.randomUUID()
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository : JpaRepository<User, UUID>{
}
```

**UserService**

```
@Service
class UserService(
        private val userRepository: UserRepository
) {
    fun getUserByID(id: UUID): Optional<User> {
        return Optional.of(
                try {
                    userRepository.getOne(id)
                } catch (e: EntityNotFoundException) {
                    User("test", "test")
                }
        )
    }

    fun addUser(user: User) {
        userRepository.save(user)
    }
}
```

**UserHandler**

```
@Component
class UserHandler(
        private val userService: UserService
) {
    fun getUserWithID(request: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
        val id = try {
            UUID.fromString(request.pathVariable("userID"))
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            return ServerResponse.badRequest().syncBody("Invalid user id")
        }
        val user = userService.getUserByID(id).get()
        return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(user))
    }
}
```

**UserRouter**

```
@Configuration
class UserRouter {
    @Bean
    fun userRoutes(userHandler: UserHandler) = router {
        contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).nest {
            GET("/users/{userID}", userHandler::getUserWithID)
            GET("") { ServerResponse.ok().build() }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

To route based on the presence of one or more query parameter (regardless of their values), we can do the following:
**UserRouter**

```
@Configuration
class UserRouter {
    @Bean
    fun userRoutes(userHandler: UserHandler) = router {

        GET("/users/{userID}", userHandler::getUserWithID)
        (GET("/users/")
                and queryParam("username") { true }
                and queryParam("password") { true }
                )
                .invoke(userHandler::getUsers)
    }
}
```

Note that `GET("/users/?username={username}", userHandler::getUsersWithUsername)` does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way the router is configured - `contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).nest` - will only match *requests* that have this content type, so you would have to either remove the contentType prerequisite or change the test to include it

```
client.get()
                .uri("/users/$id")
                .accept(MediaType.ALL)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk
                .expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .expectBody(User::class.java)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I'm also trying to get this to work with a GET request that includes a query parameter. After adding the route `GET("/users/?username={username}") { ServerResponse.ok().build() }` to my `UserRouter` (and removing the other routes) and building the query using the uri `"/users/?username=${expectedCustomer.username}"`, I again get a 404. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: This route `/users/?username=${expectedCustomer.username}` looks incorrect, it should be constructed without the trailing `/` (RFC 3986 - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3)



As for the router GET itself - I am no webflux router expert, but I believe you can define the endpoint as `GET("/users", userHandler::getUsers)`. Going from here, you can implement some logic based on query params inside the handler, like `val userId = request.queryParam("id").orElseThrow { Exception("no id provided as query param") }`.

Answer (score 6):

To all those facing the same issue, but have noticed that your issue does not involve `contentType` mismatching, **I recommend checking your dependencies (build.gradle, pom.xml, etc.)**.

In my case, I encountered the same problem when I had both of the following dependencies defined:

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
```

If you're using the functional style for declaring your endpoints (using `RouterFunction`), having both dependencies can cause issues.

**To resolve this, you should remove one of the dependencies.** If you are working with `spring-webflux`, make sure to keep only the following in your build configuration:

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
```

**Note:** It's important to note that as of `spring-boot 3.1.0`, there are no warnings or errors when both of the dependencies are present. You just receive `404 Not Found` response without any further indication of the problem.

You can find a working small application [here in the spring.io guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactive-rest-service/)

Answer (score 0):

Spent sometime to find this 404 was due to the presence of both libraries. The project could work in SpringBoot 2.7.0 but not in 3.0.5.